# SSRS Indicator that will look for both date and hour

Tags: vba, reporting-services, indicator

I have a SSRS report that uses a INDICATOR to tell if the table was updated.The issue is the table it is indicating does not get updated till 11 am so it looks like the table is not up to date before 11. My question is does anyone know if a indicator could be green if the date is greater than today and the time is greater than 11:00 am I get a error when I try to insert it saying I did not declare the hour.this is my code. My inidicator is red or green base on a 1 or 100 so if the field value is less then today it should be red and it is also set to capture the report if it does not update at 11 am. The field that is used is a date time field

`=IIF(Fields!UpdateDte.Value<Today, "1",IIFHour(Fields!UpdateDte.Value >10,"100"  ))`

Answer (score 0):

You're missing an opening parenthesis to start the second IIF and an ending parenthesis for the HOUR function.

Original Expression:

```
=IIF(Fields!UpdateDte.Value<Today, "1",IIF Hour(Fields!UpdateDte.Value >10,"100"  ))
```

Should be:

```
=IIF(Fields!UpdateDte.Value<Today, "1",IIF(Hour(Fields!UpdateDte.Value) > 10, "100"))
```